# replace image src with full image tag in string

Tags: php, html

I have this code to replace image tags in the string with their respective src..

```
$url='<img class="emojioneemoji" src="http://localhost/sng/assets/js/plugins/em/2.1.4/assets/png/1f602.png">checking<img class="emojioneemoji" src="http://localhost/sng/assets/js/plugins/em/2.1.4/assets/png/1f601.png"><img class="emojioneemoji" src="http://localhost/sng/assets/js/plugins/em/2.1.4/assets/png/1f62c.png">working check<img class="emojioneemoji" src="http://localhost/sng/assets/js/plugins/em/2.1.4/assets/png/1f600.png">';


$doc = new DOMDocument();
        @$doc->loadHTML($url);

        $tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');
        $str = "-" ;
        foreach ($tags as $tag) {
         $img_path =  $tag->getAttribute('src');
         $directory = $img_path;
         $ee = pathinfo($directory);
         $pic_name=  $ee['basename'];
         $next = "" ;
         if ($tag->nextSibling && get_class($tag->nextSibling) == "DOMText") {
            $next = $tag->nextSibling->wholeText . "-" ;
         }
         $str .= $pic_name . "-" . $next ;
        }
        echo  $str ;
```

output of above code is

```
-1f602.png-checking-1f601.png-1f62c.png-working check-1f600.png-
```

Now how can I replace this image src enclosed in "-"  to full image tag as  above?

Answer (score 0):

You can store values in array. now you can use this array to do your further work.

```
$url='<img class="emojioneemoji" src="http://localhost/sng/assets/js/plugins/em/2.1.4/assets/png/1f602.png">checking<img class="emojioneemoji" src="http://localhost/sng/assets/js/plugins/em/2.1.4/assets/png/1f601.png"><img class="emojioneemoji" src="http://localhost/sng/assets/js/plugins/em/2.1.4/assets/png/1f62c.png">working check<img class="emojioneemoji" src="http://localhost/sng/assets/js/plugins/em/2.1.4/assets/png/1f600.png">';


$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($url);

$tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');
$str = [] ;
$i = 0;

foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    $img_path =  $tag->getAttribute('src');
    $directory = $img_path;
    $ee = pathinfo($directory);
    $pic_name=  $ee['basename'];
    $next = "" ;
    if ($tag->nextSibling && get_class($tag->nextSibling) == "DOMText") {
        $next = $tag->nextSibling->wholeText;
    }

    array_push($str, ['src' => $pic_name, 'next' => $next]);
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($str);
```

Comment: i think u misunderstood
i want to replace 'check-1f602.png-checking-1f601.png-' to 'check<img src="1f602.png">checking<img src="1f601.png">'

Comment: how can we do this??